# Cannot Use or import javax.swing and java.awt in IntelliJ IDEA with jdk1.7 or 1.8

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I want to use GUI tools in Java, my IDE is IntelliJ IDEA in Win8.1 and I have:

```
java -version

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

in my path and another jdk (1.8) somewhere else.

In the commadLine (using javac) I can make/compile/build codes that are like these:

```
import java.awt.*; // Using AWT container and component classe
import java.awt.event.*; // Using AWT event classes and listener interfaces
// An AWT program inherits from the top?level container java.awt.Frame
public class AWTCounter extends Frame implements ActionListener {
private Label lblCount; // Declare component Label
private TextField tfCount; // Declare component TextField
private Button btnCount; // Declare component Button
private int count = 0; // Counter's value
```

(etc, the codes are not really important)

In my project structure in IntelliJ, I have added jdk 1.7.0_51 (same as above) but it says: "cannot resolve symbol 'event'" in the 2nd line:

import java.awt.event.*;

(the color of 'event' is red, means it does not exist)

I may have missed something about path. I spent hours searching and I didn't find anything related.

Comment: JFrame, JLabel, JTextField, JButton ...

Comment: Have you declared a project sdk?

Comment: @RobinJonsson yep. Albeit I was using IntelliJ for android development. Do I need to delete another sdks?

Comment: @RobinJonsson, And in my Run/Debug Config, I checked 'use alt JRE' and selected 1.7 (with this I can successfully build the file).

Comment: @RobinJonsson. Thanks pal. I deleted everything and added just a single sdk there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was declaring Android SDK instead of JDK in my project structure. Android software development kit does not include anything from `java.awt` or related packages because Android has it's own graphics package and libraries like `android.graphics` or `android.widget`.